# Rotation and resizing objects

Tags: c#, wpf

We are using Adorners to drag/drop, rotate and resize object on canvas. That works fine but when all the object are selected on canvas or a subset of it and we try to rotate them or resize them each object runs to a different direction. can experts give us some clue where to look at and what can be done?

it will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the similar issue. Here is the code that I implemented:

```
void DragThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        DesignerItem designerItem = this.DataContext as DesignerItem;
        DesignerCanvas designer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(designerItem) as DesignerCanvas;
        if (designerItem != null && designer != null && designerItem.IsSelected)
        {
            double minLeft = double.MaxValue;
            double minTop = double.MaxValue;

            // we only move DesignerItems
            var designerItems = designer.SelectionService.CurrentSelection.OfType<DesignerItem>();

            foreach (DesignerItem item in designerItems)
            {
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(item);
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(item);

                minLeft = double.IsNaN(left) ? 0 : Math.Min(left, minLeft);
                minTop = double.IsNaN(top) ? 0 : Math.Min(top, minTop);
            }

            double deltaHorizontal = Math.Max(-minLeft, e.HorizontalChange);
            double deltaVertical = Math.Max(-minTop, e.VerticalChange);

            foreach (DesignerItem item in designerItems)
            {
                RotateTransform rotateTransform = designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(item);
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(item);

                if (double.IsNaN(left)) left = 0;
                if (double.IsNaN(top)) top = 0;

                if (rotateTransform != null)
                {
                    Point dragDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);
                    dragDelta = rotateTransform.Transform(dragDelta);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + dragDelta.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(item, top+ dragDelta.Y);
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + deltaHorizontal);
                    Canvas.SetTop(item, top + deltaVertical);
                }
            }

            designer.InvalidateMeasure();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the bounding box solution proposed here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/54659b47-554c-47da-8158-c944687e7339

> Adorn whatever surface your selected objects are on since that is the scope of your selection. Position and size the adorner manually, instead of using the Adorner's default behaviour.